# WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to unzip 'file' when I attached file with russian name

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenoid

My selenide test failed with WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to unzip 'file' when it tried to send and attach file with cyrillic name "золотыещенки.png" at [Selenoid](http://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/).

```
unknown error: unable to unzip 'file'
from unknown error: archive error: (unknown error: could not unzip archive), entry error: (unknown error: invalid data descriptor signature)
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.13.9-coreos x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Before that it successfully attached all other files with lat names and numbers.

In code it looks like that: `$(locator).shouldBe(Condition.visible).scrollTo().sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 2):

**UPD:** this was fixed in all images - all UTF-8 encodings were generated. Should work with latest images.

---

This is because of [missing](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-images/issues/8) cyrillic encoding in browser images. A temporary workaround is to build images manually using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM selenoid/vnc:chrome_60.0

USER root
RUN locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LANG ru_RU.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE ru:en
ENV LC_ALL ru_RU.UTF-8
USER selenium
```