# WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to unzip 'file'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenoid

This question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050742/webdriverexception-unknown-error-unable-to-unzip-file-when-i-attached-file-w) but I'm not sure that the solution is. I'm getting this error when attaching a file called 'PDF_ùâàæ.pdf' using the latest image.

```
unknown error: unable to unzip 'file'
from unknown error: archive error: (unknown error: could not unzip archive), entry error: (unknown error: invalid data descriptor signature)
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

With updated image the error is the same:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to unzip 'file'
from unknown error: archive error: (unknown error: could not unzip archive), entry error: (unknown error: invalid data descriptor signature)
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562737 (dba483cee6a5f15e2e2d73df16968ab10b38a2bf),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Comment: Code trials and relevant HTML?

Comment: You have to use latest browser images.

Comment: vania-pooh, I have updated the image the latest one but still getting the same error. The exact file name is 'unique-character PDF_ùâàæ.pdf'

Comment: Need to check whether Chromedriver itself support this.